# Tkinter frame blank

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, helper

> Write a GUI program with check buttons that allow the user to select any or all of these services. When the user clicks a button the total charges would be displayed.

Simple enough. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox


class auto:

    def __init__(self):
        #create main window
        self.main_window=tkinter.Tk()

        #create frames
        self.top_frame=tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame=tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create value objects
        self.oil=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.lube=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.rad=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.trans=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.inspect=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.muff=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.tire=tkinter.IntVar()

        #set values
        self.oil.set(26)
        self.lube.set(18)
        self.rad.set(30)
        self.trans.set(80)
        self.inspect.set(15)
        self.muff.set(100)
        self.tire.set(20)

        #create checkbutton widgets
        self.oilb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text="Oil Change- $26.00" ,\
                                      variable=self.oil)
        self.lubeb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text= "Lube Job- $18.00",\
                                      variable=self.lube)
        self.radb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text= "Radiator Flush- $30.00" ,\
                                      variable=self.rad)
        self.transb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text= "Transmission Flush- $80.00",\
                                      variable=self.trans)
        self.inspectb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text= "Inspection- $15.00",\
                                      variable=self.inspect)
        self.muffb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text= "Muffler Replacement- $100.00",\
                                      variable=self.muff)
        self.tireb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,\
                                      text= "Tire Rotation- $20.00",\
                                      variable=self.tire)

    def display_charge():
        total=0
        for var in(self.oil,self.lube,self.rad,self.trans,self.inspect,self.muff,self.tire):
            total+=var.get()
            total_l.config(text="{}.00".format(total))

        #pack the check buttons
        self.oilb.pack()
        self.lubeb.pack()
        self.radb.pack()
        self.transb.pack()
        self.inspectb.pack()
        self.muffb.pack()
        self.tireb.pack()

        #create charge and quit buttons
        self.display_button=tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                            text= "Display Charges", command=self.display_charge)
        self.quit_button=tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,\
                            text="Quit", command=self.mainwindow.destory)

        #pack the buttons
        self.display_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #pack frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #start main loop
        tkinter.mainloop()

mygui=auto()
```

When I run the program, the frame is blank. What have I done wrong?
I'm also having a problem getting the total charges **(I have no idea how)**.
But that dilemma is void if I can't even get the frame to show properly.

How do I get things to show in the frame, and how do I calculate total charges?

Comment: Looks awfully similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29958692/4203871) question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code had several problems.

1. Nonstandard class structure of a `tkinter` app, including initialization and `mainloop()`.
2. Typos, such as `mainwindow`/`main_window` and `destroy`/`destory`.
3. `display_charge()` was doing a lot more than displaying the charge; it was doing half the GUI setup as well.
4. `display_charge()` referenced a `total_l` object that didn't exist.
5. `Checkbutton`s don't work like that. When you clear them, they are set to 0, and when you check them, they are set to 1. If you `set()` them with custom values, they will be correct until you toggle them, at which point they will revert to their default values. To properly give them custom values, use the `offvalue` and `onvalue` attributes.
6. It's a style problem rather than a functionality problem, but try not to use explicit line continuation (`\`) unless it's necessary.

---

```
import tkinter

class auto:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # create reference to main window
        self.main_window = parent

        #create frames
        self.top_frame=tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame=tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create value objects
        self.oil=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.lube=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.rad=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.trans=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.inspect=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.muff=tkinter.IntVar()
        self.tire=tkinter.IntVar()

        #create checkbutton widgets
        self.oilb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text="Oil Change- $26.00" ,
                                      variable=self.oil, onvalue=26)
        self.lubeb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text= "Lube Job- $18.00",
                                      variable=self.lube, onvalue=18)
        self.radb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text= "Radiator Flush- $30.00" ,
                                      variable=self.rad, onvalue=30)
        self.transb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text= "Transmission Flush- $80.00",
                                      variable=self.trans, onvalue=80)
        self.inspectb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text= "Inspection- $15.00",
                                      variable=self.inspect, onvalue=15)
        self.muffb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text= "Muffler Replacement- $100.00",
                                      variable=self.muff, onvalue=100)
        self.tireb=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame,
                                      text= "Tire Rotation- $20.00",
                                      variable=self.tire, onvalue=20)

        #create charge and quit buttons
        self.display_button=tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                            text= "Display Charges", command=self.display_charge)
        self.quit_button=tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                            text="Quit", command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.total_l = tkinter.Label(self.bottom_frame, text="$0.00")

        #pack frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #pack the check buttons
        self.oilb.pack()
        self.lubeb.pack()
        self.radb.pack()
        self.transb.pack()
        self.inspectb.pack()
        self.muffb.pack()
        self.tireb.pack()

        #pack the buttons
        self.display_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')
        self.total_l.pack(side='left')

    def display_charge(self):
        self.total_l.config(text="${}.00".format(sum(map(tkinter.IntVar.get,
        [self.oil, self.lube, self.rad, self.trans, self.inspect, self.muff,
        self.tire]))))

root=tkinter.Tk()
mygui=auto(root)
root.mainloop()
```